# Modify scrollbar in React without external dependencies

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scrollbar

I'm trying to modify the look of the scrollbar in my ReactJS application.

Basically, I would like to have something like the following:

[image]

I've tried to use CSS properties, e.g. `-webkit-scrollbar`, `-webkit-scrollbar-track` and `-webkit-scrollbar-thumb`, but I don't see any changes.

I searched online, but all I can find are 3rd party libraries which provide custom scrollbars.

Is there any way to do that without having to rely on an external dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do this using css only but browser support isn't that great which is why many JavaScript solutions exist. You can reduce the width of the  -webkit-scrollbar-track by modifying the border-right and left:

```
border-left: 5px solid gray;
border-right: 5px solid gray;
```

As for the -webkit-scrollbar-thumb you can make it look as the image you provided by modifying the border radius:

```
border-radius: 10px;
```

the width of the scrollbar can be modified using the -webkit-scrollbar:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px;
}
```

Modifying a pen I found to look close to your desired design:
https://codepen.io/rasso/pen/QWWxPQo

```css
html {
  background: #2a2d46;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  height: 100%;

  overflow: scroll;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 3em;
  font: 100%/1.4 serif;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
p {
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 15px;
  background: #4d4e5a;
  color: #333;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #595a62;
  border-left: 5px solid #2a2d46;
  border-right: 5px solid #2a2d46;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem deleniti accusantium quasi ab ad officia cupiditate sed aliquam nobis expedita velit dolorum perspiciatis pariatur nam vero et magnam soluta tempora!</div>
<div>Eveniet deserunt consequatur porro molestiae nulla optio quis totam libero iste nemo odit eum facilis sapiente. Harum similique cupiditate voluptas ea optio sunt molestias eius ab qui obcaecati nesciunt id?</div>
<div>Necessitatibus delectus sint vitae eos quasi optio esse dignissimos enim laborum ipsum harum perspiciatis eaque. Magnam fugiat delectus neque laboriosam in accusamus a veniam inventore asperiores consequatur nihil quae quo.</div>
<div>Eligendi quaerat nesciunt sint nobis qui? Temporibus maiores esse molestiae hic cum culpa sed recusandae dolore sequi modi. Quos illum debitis odio consequatur voluptatum error aliquam rem similique officia recusandae.</div>
<div>Ex suscipit earum reiciendis eaque dolorem inventore accusantium modi voluptatum saepe cum quam tempora autem corrupti illum deleniti iure rerum mollitia quo ducimus soluta ea! Illum aliquid consectetur vitae quod?</div>
<div>Minus rem tempora quo. Deleniti mollitia dignissimos laborum quis quos facilis dolore soluta error provident recusandae veniam minus consequatur blanditiis. Facere tempore praesentium soluta fugiat quia eligendi dolores ullam doloribus!</div>
<div>Aut nulla perferendis officiis accusamus ut aspernatur hic possimus amet blanditiis incidunt repudiandae ullam inventore ipsam recusandae nihil provident facilis totam quibusdam natus eligendi optio quia sapiente rerum quos illo?</div>
<div>Porro soluta nisi impedit voluptatem ex accusantium facilis amet quod blanditiis quia similique totam enim id ratione minus quo modi sequi nam dicta iste aliquid itaque velit accusamus quibusdam consequuntur.</div>
<div>Ab assumenda in ad nesciunt recusandae labore voluptates vero suscipit tenetur ullam sint beatae odio harum quo aperiam quas temporibus pariatur consectetur saepe eveniet minus voluptatem atque iusto similique repudiandae?</div>
<div>In enim odit repellat maxime harum eum expedita fuga vel eaque quaerat optio hic sapiente eveniet neque dolorum eligendi pariatur possimus aliquid minus officiis mollitia quia voluptates sunt nulla est!</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Ali. But the problem is that I don't know how to use the `-webkit-scrollbar` and the rest of the scrollbar elements with ReactJS. I've tried a similar solution and has no effect with React.

Comment: Why don't you create a css class and reference the element to it instead of using the style prop. Just use the className prop to reference the css class.